# Pathfinder character creation using multiple books

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

Is there a good resource that leads you step by step through creating a character using more than just the core book? For example, if I choose an Elf character, it reminds you that there are variant choices in Elves of Golarion and the Advanced Race Guide etc?

Ideally I'm not looking for character creation software, more something that leads you through the books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest thing I know of would be the d20pfsrd.com website.  And even then, its more that it has a lot of that sort of information available in one place, and does reference it's existence.

But I found something for you [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scoreforge/)

Comment: ... you just need to be a bit careful about making sure that you're using approved sources (many GMs will allow "all Paizo books", but 3rd party stuff will require permission).

Comment: I do find that site useful, but it's not quite the same. Seems like this would be a great resource to build!

Comment: A Heroforge version for pathfinder would be awesome, if it exists.

Comment: Can you say more about Scoreforge? What is it, why does it meet what the asker's looking for, does it actually work?

Comment: sCoreForge looks like great software, but as per the original post I'm looking for a resource that guides me through the books rather than a program that centralises the options into one list like PCGen

Comment: Sorry bout that, didn't catch that part the first time I read through it.  The creation of something along the lines you are asking about would certainly be handy in giving the players a guideline at character creation as to what is or is not allowed.